# What functors are these?

Tags: category-theory

The category of "just arrow" categories is equivalent to Cat [as we see here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76083/categories-presented-with-arrows-only-no-objects-partial-monoids?lq=1).  If we have a "just arrow" category $C$, I think we can also have the set of equations, $EQ_C$, over the (compositions of) the arrows of $C$.  These equations are extra data that define $C$.  I am not sure if this is possible.  We see our "just arrow" category as a monoid of arrows with a partial composition defined over the arrows (so $D \subset C \times C$ and $f: D \rightarrow C$ defines composition).  Furthermore, the extra data that really defines $C$ are equations over compositions (words) in the arrows of $C$.  So, for every "just arrow" category $C$, there should be a set of equations that (along with the compositions) define it, and I am calling it $EQ_C$.

Consider the category of "just arrow" categories $JA$.  Next, consider two cats $A, B \in JA$ such that $EQ_A \subset EQ_B$.  I think there should be an obvious functor $F : A \rightarrow B$ which is just an inclusion of the equations in $A$ into the equations of $B$.  Is this a familiar functor? Does it have a name?

Edit: It has been pointed out that the simple criteria of $EQ_A \subset EQ_B$ does not give rise to a functor in general.  Can we define $A$ such that there does exist such a functor?  I mean, define $A$ in relation to $B$?

Comment: I don't understand what you call $EQ_A$, can you be more precise? You mean the subset of $A \times A$ of composable arrows? If so I don't see why inclusion would be a functor.

Comment: I will try to be more explicit, but please read the link in the post.

Comment: I have read the link in the post and I didn't see the notation "$EQ_A$" anywhere, did I miss it?

Comment: Perhaps I need to start there, and ask "given a just arrow category, C, can we have the set of equations for C?"

Comment: Suppose you have a monoid, with a partial composition (not all elements compose) and you then define equations over words in your "partial monoid".  If you had a finite presentation of your partial monoid, you should have some set of equations that define it.  The same is true for "just arrow" categories.

Comment: If I'm understanding things correctly, shouldn't there be a functor in the opposite direction $B \rightarrow A$? Like a quotient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such functor doesn't exist in general case. For example, let $A=\{1\}$ (the category of arrows, corresponding to the trivial monoid) and $B=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (the category of arrows, corresponding to the multiplicative monoid of integers modulo $2$, whose arrows are $0$ and $1$). Note, that $EQ_A\subset EQ_B$, but the inclusion mapping $i\colon\{1\}\to\{0,1\}$ doesn't induce a functor.

But such inclusion functor exists if we define the notion of "just arrow subcategory". I will try to do that.

**Definition.** Let $A$ and $B$ be $JA$-categories (i.e. sets with partial binary operations, satisfying axioms of category). Then $A$ is a $JA$-subcategory of $B$ iff

1. $A\subset B$;
2. for every pair $(f,g)\in A\times A$, if it is composable in $B$, then it is composable in $A$ and compositions coincide;
3. for every arrow $f\in A$, its left and right identities in $B$ also belong to $A$.

In this case the inclusion mapping $i\colon A\to B$ is a $JA$-functor.

The example from the first paragraph shows that $EQ_A\subset EQ_B$ doesn't imply the third axiom of this definition. I leave it as exercise to check that it also doesn't imply the second axiom.

Comment: Yes, ok, the idea isn't totally general.  But can we define $A$ such that the functor exists?  In that case, how do we see such a functor?

Comment: @BenSprott The most natural idea to do that is to define the analogue of the notion of _subcategory_ for "just arrow" categories. I will edit it in.