# A complete category of categories and embeddings

Tags: category-theory

I have a theory that you should be able to construct a category of categories and embeddings that is complete.  Someone already [pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647145/is-this-category-complete-or-cauchy-complete) that if the functors are full and faithful, your cat is not complete.  Can we choose a type of embedding that ensures that the cat is complete?  My intuition is coming from "just arrow categories" [as seen here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646440/what-functors-are-these).  In that post, I am trying to find the definiton of a functor and the responder has suggested the definition of subcategory for "just arrow" cats.  Am I wrong in thinking that there is an embedding (not full faithful) that constructs a complete cat?  What if we reverse the arrows and consider quotients in the "just arrow" categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in your previous questions, $\mathbf{Cat}$ is equivalent to $JA-\mathbf{Cat}$. To understand anything categorical about $JA-\mathbf{Cat}$ is to understand it about $\mathbf{Cat}$, because all categorical properties are stable under equivalence.

However, the wide subcategory of $\mathbf{Cat}$, whose arrows are (any types of) embeddings is not complete. The obvious reason is that it has no terminal object. So is the category $JA-\mathbf{Cat}$.

Regarding your question about $JA$-quotients: yes, $JA-\mathbf{Cat}$ has quotients, but they are much more sophisticated, then subcategories, as well as in $\mathbf{Cat}$. See [Generalized congruences -- Epimorphisms in Cat](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/1999/n11/5-11abs.html) for description of epimorphisms.

Comment: Amazing and very helpful thanks so much!

Comment: Hi @Oskar, I am trying to do a calculation which is the calculation of colimits in Cat (and have been advised to do it with coproducts and coequalizers).  [Here is a link](https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/6903/approximations-to-frel-in-cat/#Item_3) to my explanation page at nforum.  I really need help doing the calculation, so if you would like to help, that would be great!